# django-non rel app not found

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using django-non rel for the first time. I already had a simple django project. I created an app named job_board and added into the installed apps tuple. I copied my existing models, views, and template over and updated the urls.

After doing manage.py runserver I get the error:

> name 'job_board' is not defined

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'job_board',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^_ah/warmup$', 'djangoappengine.views.warmup'),
    (r'^$', job_board.views.main_page),
    (r'^edit-job/$', job_board.views.edit_job),
    (r'^edit-job/(?P<job_id>\d+)$', job_board.views.edit_job),
    (r'^job-details/(?P<job_id>\d+)$', job_board.views.job_details),
    (r'^edit-location/$', job_board.views.edit_location),
    (r'^edit-location/(?P<job_id>\d+)/(?P<location_id>\d+)$', job_board.views.edit_location),
    (r'^edit-customer/$', job_board.views.edit_customer),
    (r'^edit-customer/(?P<job_id>\d+)/(?P<customer_id>\d+)$', job_board.views.edit_customer),
)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a module directly in urls.py (rather than referring to it as a string) you need to import it first.

Comment: wow i'm dumb. thanks I'm new to python and django and often overlook importing modules. thanks!